# Why multilevel dynamic local tasks doesn't work?

Tags: 8, routes

I want to have tabs, but since they need to be dynamic I am making use of local tasks. In the class extending `DeriverBase` I have written the following function:

```
public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $this->derivatives = array();
    foreach ($this->moduleFormatManager->getDefinitions() as $key => $definition) {
      $this->derivatives[$key]['title'] = $definition['title'];
      $this->derivatives[$key]['route_parameters'] = array('module_format' => $key);
      $this->derivatives[$key]['route_name'] = 'module.format_configure_' . $key;
      if($key == 'xyz') {
        $key = 'newkey';
      $this->derivatives[$key]['title'] = 'newkey';
      $this->derivatives[$key]['route_name'] = 'module.newkey';
      $this->derivatives[$key]['parent_id'] = "module.format_configure:xyz";
      }
    }
    foreach ($this->derivatives as &$entry) {
      $entry += $base_plugin_definition;
    }
    return $this->derivatives;
  }
```

In the above code, a tab for each key is being generated: my problem is in the if condition. In the if condition I am trying to generate a sub tab for a particular type of tab by declaring `parent_id`. But the code doesn't work for me.

What changes should I introduce in order to make it work? I used this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122253) to learn about local tasks.

My `module.links.tasks.yml` file looks like this:

```
module.format_configure:
  title: 'Configuration'
  base_route: module.configure
  tab_root_id: module.configure
  deriver: 'path to deriver'
```

All the mentioned routes have been declared in `*.routing.yml` file.

Comment: Have a look at how Field UI is doing it.

Comment: @IvanJaros I have already looked in that module but couldn't find my mistake hence asking here.

Comment: Have you properly set the class and deriver in your module's links.task.yml file?

Comment: @IvanJaros I have updated my answer with the expected code in my links.tasks.yml file.

Comment: How is the behaviour happening in the UI directl/

Comment: @DanielWehner sorry but I didn't understood your question. Currently each tab by this line `$this->derivatives[$key]['title'] = $definition['title'];` is being generated, problem is in this line `$this->derivatives[$key]['title'] = 'newkey';`  because sub tab is not being generated.

Answer (score 1):

You said your file is called `module.links.tasks.yml`. The correct filename is `module.links.task.yml` (note links word is pluralized, but task is not).